# Tasks support was removed in SonarQube 7.6

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, dockerfile, devops, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to install `sonar-scanner-cli` using Dockerfile but getting the below error:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.4.0.2170
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.4.17-2011.0.7.el7uek.x86_64 amd64
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 7.7.0
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=62ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AWoRdxW1J_VH_hnihanC
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=39ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=937ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2.300s
INFO: Final Memory: 4M/17M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Tasks support was removed in SonarQube 7.6.
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Here is my Dockerfile and `sonar-runner.properties` file:

```
FROM sonatypenexus.com:19443/ubuntu:20.04

COPY ./nexus.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm; \
    apt update; \
    apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk;

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin

RUN echo $JAVA_HOME; \
    echo $PATH; \
    java -version;

RUN apt install -y git;
RUN apt-get install maven -y;
RUN apt-get install docker.io -y;
RUN docker --version;
RUN apt-get install -y curl tmux htop sudo unzip wget;

# Set timezone to CST
ENV TZ=America/Chicago
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
COPY ./sonar-scanner-cli-4.4.0.2170-linux.zip /usr/src/sonarscanner.zip

WORKDIR /usr/src

RUN unzip sonarscanner.zip && \
    rm sonarscanner.zip && \
    mv sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170-linux /usr/lib/sonar-scanner && \
  ln -s /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner /usr/local/bin/sonar-scanner

ENV SONAR_RUNNER_HOME=/usr/lib/sonar-scanner
COPY sonar-runner.properties /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
ENTRYPOINT ["sonar-scanner"]
CMD ["-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/usr/src"]
```

Here is my sonar-runner.properties file:

```
sonar.host.url=http://uxunt:8080/sonarqube

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://sonarqube/sonar
sonar.projectKey=MyProjectKey
sonar.projectName=My Project Name
sonar.projectVersion=1
sonar.projectBaseDir=/usr/src
sonar.sources=./
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on answers in SonarSourve Community, [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/tasks-support-was-removed-in-sonarqube-7-6/29476) and [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/tasks-support-was-removed-after-downloading-plugin/10598), my guess is you should be quoting `sonar.projectName='My Project Name'`.

> This is not actually about your analysis parameters but about your
> analysis command.
>
> You have something on the command line which you likely intended to be
> an argument but which is not prefixed with a dash (-). Because there’s
> no dash, the scanner interprets it as an argument/task.

Comment: If you find this answer addressed your problem, please mark as "Accepted" (the tick box). If you found it useful, please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it might be helpful.
Put the project token along with the sonars-scanner command. -X for debug.

**Windows**

C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\sonar-scanner-4.8.0.2856-windows\bin> sonar-scanner -Dsonar.token=//put your projectkey// -X

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting  `Tasks support was removed in SonarQube 7.6` error because I wrote `sonar.token` inside `sonar-project.properties` file.

Solved it by providing token as option to scanner

Eg : `sonar-scanner -Dsonar.token=sqp_xxxxx -Dsonar.sources=.`